# Sending multipart requests using Spring Boot with specific header for every part

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data, resttemplate

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILbhN.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILbhN.png]]

As mentioned in image I would like to send content-type as application/json for a particular part of a multipart request in springboot application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use MultipartBodyBuilder to build your request.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

headers.add("add custome header", "header value");

MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();

builder.part("json_part", "").header("Content-Type", "application/json");

MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> body = builder.build();

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(body, 
headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().build();

ResponseEntity<String> postResponse = restTemplate
    .postForEntity("yoururl", requestEntity, String.class);
```